# How to join multiple Matlab tables stored in a structure

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a multiple tables stored in a structure. I would like to merge all of them. The number of rows are not the same but the number of columns are the same. The common key is always in the first column.

For two tables it's easy to do the join but it's a little bit tricky with multiple ones. How can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I can think of is to poll your current workspace and see what variables currently exist.  Then, for each variable, if it's a structure, concatenate this onto a larger structure.  When you're done, you'll have one large structure that contains all of these combined.  This will require the use of [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) and unfortunately [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
%// Larger structure initialization
largeStruct = [];

%// Get all variable names currently in workspace
vars = whos;

%// For each variable...
for ii = 1 : numel(vars)
    %// If this is a structure, and if the variable is not any of
    %// the current structure, the automatic variable answer and
    %// the current variable storing our variable names...
    if strcmpi(vars(ii).class, 'struct') && ~any(strcmpi(vars(ii).name, {'largeStruct', 'ans', 'vars'}))
        %// Concatenate to the larger structure
        largeStruct = eval(['[largeStruct ' vars(ii).name '];']);
    end
end
```

---

BTW, [using `eval` is considered bad practice](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).  I had to use it because of your current state of the workspace.  Consider using a single structure that stores all of these nested structures where the fields are the actual variable names themselves... something like `stock.stockQuotes_070715, stock.stockQuotes_070815`, etc.  If you did it this way, we wouldn't have had to use `eval` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I would poll the workspace, put all the datasets in a cell array, use cellfun to convert to tables, and then use a recursive outerjoin function like this:

```
tablecell = {Table1, Table2, Table3, ...}
tables = outerjoinmultiple(tablecell)


function table = outerjoinmultiple(tables)

if size(tables, 2) == 1
    table = tables{1};
else
    t2 = outerjoinmultiple(tables(2:end));
    table = outerjoin(tables{1}, t2, 'MergeKeys', true);
end
```